# cocoa opengl how to show multiple viewports

Tags: cocoa, opengl

I am using the example from: http://dragonsandbytecode.wordpress.com/2012/06/07/game-dev-diary-5-about-textures-and-2d/

and i want to show multiple viewports, preferably that i am able to switch them on and off by pressing 1,2,3,4 etc. But first things first, how do i show multiple viewports? In the following function:

```
- (void)reshape {
NSRect rect = [self bounds];

glViewport(0, rect.size.height/2, rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(50, rect.size.width/rect.size.height, .1, 30);


glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

}

If i write more then one glviewport, it overwrites the other. I read somewhere that i have to make opengl draw to the screen first again, but how do i do that? I do apologize if i sound clueless, but i highly appreciate anyone who could help me out here. In GLUT i always used subwindows, but seeing that would use many different contexts i think the better way is to use glViewport() instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you call glviewport again, you're simply going to be setting the same OpenGL context's viewport to a new rectangle, overwriting the previous setting, which clearly is not what you want.

If your various OpenGL-based views are in different areas of the screen, with non-OpenGL content between them, then in OpenGL-speak, what you need  is to use a separate GL context for each one (which you can achieve by using multiple views based on NSOpenGLView). Or, if your GL views are adjacent, you'd find it much simpler using a single OpenGL context (like you're doing), but drawing everything in the one place.

As for multiple contexts with GLUT within the same window, it doesn't look to me like this is possible. Instead, I'd strongly recommend moving to using the OpenGL integration (NSOpenGLView, NSOpenGLContext, etc) that Apple has provided. See here: https://developer.apple.com/opengl/